# Launch/Show Microsoft Visual Studio IDE programmatically using C++?

Tags: c++

Can somebody help me with a C++ example to launch Microsoft Visual Studio 8.0 IDE (integrated development environment).

Basically i am able to work with these Inetrafce VCProjectEngine,VCProject,.. methods to create and VCProject programmatically. but couldn't find a function/method to launch the IDE.

I know there is something called EnvDTE but couldn't find working C++ sample for it.

Any help is much appriciated!

Background:
Some of you may be aware that VBA 7.1 (Visual Basic for Applications 7.1) 64-bit version doesn't support Microsoft Common Controls (MSCOMCTL.OCX), So i wanted to take out (remove) VBA which was integrated and re-disrtibuted with my application and replace it with Microsoft Visual Studio IDE and expose my automation interface to it.

Thanks and regards,
Nayaz

Answer (score 0):

You can just `ShellExecute` the project or solution file.

Comment: Hi MSalters,

I dont want to go with ShellExecute/ExecuteProcess..so on. Looking for some Visual Studio API's to do that.

Thank you for your quick response.
regards,
Nayaz